# Using a variable as a dict key

Tags: python, json

I have JSON objects coming in:

```
{"Name":"server1","NodeID":1063,"RowID":"3","Vendor":"HP","Load":"41"},
{"Name":"server2","NodeID":1064,"RowID":"7","Vendor":"HP","Load":"12"},
{"Name":"server82","NodeID":1064,"RowID":12","Vendor":"HP","Load":"2"},
{"Name":"server242","NodeID":1064,"RowID":"4","Vendor":"HP","Load":"1"},
{"Name":"server572","NodeID":1064,"RowID":"4","Vendor":"HP","Load":"44"},
{"Name":"server8","NodeID":1064,"RowID":"2","Vendor":"HP","Load":"23"},
{"Name":"server8","NodeID":1064,"RowID":"7","Vendor":"HP","Load":"1"},
...
```

And I am outputting a different format, here is the dict before I feed it to `urllib.request`.

```
import json
import urllib.request

machine = {}
machine['_type'] = "general_data"
machine['_system'] = "LinuxDataCpu"
machine['_device'] = i['Name']
machine['CPUload1'] = i['Load']
```

If this was a bash script,  CPUload$RowID would likely form the basis of the solution.

I have some machines with 1 CPU, some with 8, and some with 12.
I have a JSON object `machine()` that will be created and pushed out in a post.
Each JSON object will contain only one CPU value, so the key needs to reflect which cpu is being reported (1 to 12).

How do I use a variable for a key such that I can indicate a different key name for each CPU?

So the first line for `server1` would get:

```
machine['CPUload3'] = i['Load']
```

And the second line gets:

```
machine['CPUload7'] = i['Load']
```

For the respective output `key: value` pair.  Each line only reports one row at a time, so a 12 cpu machine would randomly send reports listing individual cpu's.  On the back end nothing is random, but the raw sql generating the data is not ordering the data in any way.  The data is actually a large block of data, but the API I am sending the json to can only take one key value pair for the data.  it *should* let me pass the whole json object, but decisions were made out of my control, and one payload variable is allowd per post.

Michael Butscher offers: "['CPUload' + i['RowID']]"...  this was what I was looking for.  (yeah I'm a rookie hack with python).

Type it up Michael and I'll mark it to give you the credit.

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: This question could use a bit of rewording, it is unclear to me what you are asking.. perhaps some more examples of structured data on input and output, etc.

Comment: Something like `machine['CPUload' + i['RowID']] = ...`?

Comment: do you mean to have just one key `f'CPUload{k}'` where `k` is the CPU count for that machine? And is that value `k` somehow indicated by `'RowID'` in the initial JSON?

Comment: We have a winner!!  Something like machine['CPUload' + i['RowID']] = ...? – 
Thanks to Michael Butscher.....  Michael turn that comment into a one-line answer, and I'll give you credit.  And yes, this is simple string manipulation, and I'm only starting to use python.  A rookie...

Answer (score 0):

Just create a string variable, pass the incremental server number via a loop and pass the string variable into the key.

Something like:

```
incrementalCPUnumber = 1
key = 'CPUload{0}'.format(incrementalCPUnumber)
machine[x] = i['Load']
```

I think you'll need to clarify more, but on face value, this is what it seems like you are trying to do.